# Google Maps API null pointer JSONObject

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm try to develop a location based app. I try to draw a route but program returns to me a `NullPointerException`.

I faced this problem at line 361.

[MapsActivity.java](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12018911/)

```
package com.example.tcarcelik.glympse;

/**
 * Created by TCARCELIK on 09.07.2015.
 */

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeContentAd;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Parcelable,LocationListener {

    LatLng destination;
    Polyline line;
    Button mBtnDest;
    Button btnDraw;
    Button btnOk;
    Button btnNextStep;
    int counter;

    GoogleMap mMap;
    EditText editPlace_Dest;

    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
    ArrayList<LatLng> list;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private static final long MIN_TIME = 400;
    private static final float MIN_DISTANCE = 1000;

    double mLatitude = 0;
    double mLongitude = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        btnDraw = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_draw);
        btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                destination = point;
                mMap.clear();
                drawMarker(point);
                markerPoints.add(point);

                FrameLayout mapLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.map);

                btnDraw.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        double lat1 = mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude();
                        double long1 = mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude();

                        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(lat1, long1);

                        String url = getDirectionsUrl(latlng, destination);

                        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                        downloadTask.execute(url);
                    }
                });

                // Button of OK
                btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("listToPass", list);

                       // CameraPosition myCam = mMap.getCameraPosition();
                        ArrayList<Double> first_param = new ArrayList<Double>();
                        ArrayList<Double> second_param = new ArrayList<Double>();
                            for(LatLng point:list){
                                first_param.add(point.latitude);
                                second_param.add(point.longitude);
                            }

                        Collections.sort(first_param);
                        Collections.sort(second_param);

                        double lat_min = first_param.get(0);
                        double lat_max = first_param.get(first_param.size()-1);

                        double lng_min = second_param.get(0);
                        double lng_max = second_param.get(second_param.size()-1);

                        LatLng bound_1 = new LatLng(lat_min,lng_min);
                        LatLng bound_2 = new LatLng(lat_max,lng_max);
                        LatLngBounds mainbound = new LatLngBounds(bound_1,bound_2);

                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mainbound,100));

                        CameraPosition myCam = mMap.getCameraPosition();
                        i.putExtra("cameraPosition", myCam);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
          locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
          locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, (LocationListener) this);
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            if (mMap != null) {
                //  setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    public GoogleMap get_MapsMap(){
        return mMap;
    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();
            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    }

    /** A class, to download Places from Geocoding webservice */
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        String data = null;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try{
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        // Draw path'in onPostExecute ' u
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            // Instantiating ParserTask which parses the json data from Geocoding webservice
            // in a non-ui thread
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Start parsing the places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
            drawPath(result); // Ben ekledim

            if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if(progressDialog == null){
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Drawing route");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Geocoding Places in non-ui thread */
    class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

        JSONObject jObject;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
            GeocodeJSONParser parser = new GeocodeJSONParser();

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                /** Getting the parsed data as a an ArrayList */
                places = parser.parse(jObject);

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){

        }
    }

    //YENI EKLENENLER

    private void drawMarker(LatLng point){
        markerPoints.add(point);

        // Creating MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting the position of the marker
        options.position(point);

        mMap.addMarker(options);
    }

    public void drawPath(String result){
        try {
            final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray routeArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
            JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            String encodedString = overviewPolylines.getString("points");
            list = (ArrayList<LatLng>) decodePoly(encodedString);

            PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
            for (int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++) {
                LatLng point = list.get(z);
                options.add(point);
            }
            line = mMap.addPolyline(options);

            // Animate camera after drawing route
            ArrayList<Double> first_param = new ArrayList<Double>();
            ArrayList<Double> second_param = new ArrayList<Double>();
            for(LatLng point:list){
                first_param.add(point.latitude);
                second_param.add(point.longitude);
            }

            Collections.sort(first_param);
            Collections.sort(second_param);

            double lat_min = first_param.get(0);
            double lat_max = first_param.get(first_param.size()-1);

            double lng_min = second_param.get(0);
            double lng_max = second_param.get(second_param.size()-1);

            LatLng bound_1 = new LatLng(lat_min,lng_min);
            LatLng bound_2 = new LatLng(lat_max,lng_max);
            LatLngBounds mainbound = new LatLngBounds(bound_1,bound_2);

            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mainbound, 100));
            // Animate camera after drawing route

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
        mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
        locationManager.removeUpdates((LocationListener) this);

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    //YENI EKLENENLER
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }

    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        //    TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
        //    tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `result` null perhaps?

Comment: But it was working and i think i didn't change anything. Why is result turns null in your opinion?

Comment: I'm not saying I this, necessarily; but it would at very least be useful to know what it is at this point. Can you log it or set a breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

please, debug and make sure you are correctly downloading the file, check the downloadUrl(String strUrl) method and make sure it reaches line 256. i believe the problem is with the download method.

Comment: But actually i have to onPostExecute and i didn't use this one.

Comment: i thought you modified the result on the first asynctask.  let me update my answer.